# How do you use this array instead of asking for input?

Tags: c++, arrays

Learning about arrays in class. Trying to understand them by playing with the code below using my arrays instead of this sample below.

example of array:

```
string[16] = {"Toelle","Red Lightning","Penguins","Tigers","You Know It","VP4LIFE","OG      WOW","Indy","Ok","NOSER","LAK State","THE State","NY","Ks","Tahaa","Fosda"};
```

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// This program inputs a list of team names and runs a random tournament to find the winner.

void print_teams(string *ptr, int size)
{
    for(int team = 0; team < size; team++)
    {
        cout << "Team "<<team<<"="<<ptr[team]<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    const int NTEAMS=4;
    string *teams = new string[NTEAMS];

    // Get input from the user for the teams
    for(int team = 0; team < NTEAMS; team++)
    {
        cout <<"Enter the name for team #"<<team<<":";
        getline(cin, teams[team]);
    }
    print_teams(teams, NTEAMS);

    int teams_left = NTEAMS;
    string *team_ptr = teams;

    for(int round = 0; teams_left > 1; round++) {
        // Allocate space for the winners
        int new_size = teams_left/2;
        string *new_teams = new string[new_size];
        // Run a round of the tournament
        for(int team = 0; team < teams_left; team+=2) 
        {
            // Pick a winner
            int winner = rand()%2;
            //update the winners array
            new_teams[team/2] = team_ptr[team+winner];
        }
        cout << "Round "<<round<<endl;
        print_teams(new_teams, new_size);
        // Update the size and team pointer for the next round
        teams_left = new_size;
        // Free up the space for the old teams list
        delete[] team_ptr;
        team_ptr = new_teams;
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: If your size is a compile-time constant, you don't need to dynamically allocate memory for the array.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev "How do you use this array instead of asking for input?"

Comment: You just have to access `input_array[team]` instead of reading from `cin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the code which works with the array to a separate function, which receives the array as a parameter. That array can be read from cin, or hardcoded, or from any other source. That way you can reuse your code for both cases. The key concept here is decoupling input from actual computation.